# want to change window color using XAML RESOURCE FILE

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, resources

I want to change the color of a window by applying style which is defined in XAML RESOURCE FILE. I have created a style with target type set to window with no key (assuming that it will be applied automatically to all windows). But the style is not applied to the windows in my App. using below code only works for controls in window,but it is not changing the color of window itself. Please let me know where i am wrong.**If i give target type grid it changes the color, but if i give window then it is not changing the color**

**resource file**

```
<Color x:Key="MainBackgroundColor"></Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainBackground" 
                    Color="{Binding Path=DataContext.MainApplicationColor,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}, 
    FallbackValue={StaticResource MainBackgroundColor}}"/>


<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainBackground}" />            
</Style>
```

***view***

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmLight1.View.MainMenuView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"  Name="x_main" 
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/ColorResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Height="60" Width="60">
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**view Model***

```
public string ChangeColorCommandText { get; set; }
private RelayCommand m_cmdChangeColor;
public ICommand ChangeColor
{
    get { return m_cmdChangeColor ?? (m_cmdChangeColor = new RelayCommand(ChangeColorAction, () => true)); }
}


private void ChangeColorAction()
{
    MainApplicationColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#4484F3");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the Target type is not applied to your Window is because, here you are using a derived type of a window with name "MainMenuView". **TargetType in Styles doesn't manage derived types**. So in your style resource you have to set the target type as the derived type (MainMenuView). By doing so it will be applied only to the MainMenuView window.

```
xmlns:local="Yournamespace:YourApplication"

<Style  TargetType="local:MainMenuView">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

To apply the style to all your windows in your app, then it is necessary that you have to set the x:Key for the defined style and reference the style from all windows either in xaml or in code behind.